# Checkpoint for many streaming source

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, spark-structured-streaming

im working with zeppelin ,I read many files from many source in spark streaming like this :

```
    val var1 = spark
  .readStream
  .schema(var1_raw)      
  .option("sep", ",")  
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")  
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 100)
  .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
  .option("newFilesOnly", "true") 
  .csv(path_var1 )    


val chekpoint_var1 =  var1
    .writeStream
    .format("csv") 
    .option("checkpointLocation", path_checkpoint_var1) 
    .option("Path",path_checkpoint )  
    .option("header", true)  
    .outputMode("Append")
    .queryName("var1_backup")
    .start().awaitTermination()


val var2 = spark
    .readStream
  .schema(var2_raw)      
  .option("sep", ",")  
  .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")  //
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 100)
  .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") 
  .option("newFilesOnly", "true") 
  .csv(path_var2 )   

val chekpoint_var2 =  var2
    .writeStream
    .format("csv") 
    .option("checkpointLocation", path_checkpoint_var2)   //
    .option("path",path_checkpoint_2 )  
    .option("header", true)  
    .outputMode("Append")
    .queryName("var2_backup")
    .start().awaitTermination()
```

when i re run the job i got this message :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot start query with name var1_backup as a query with that name is already active

*****************the solution*******************

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("test")
    .config("spark.local", "local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(path_checkpoint)
```

and after i call the checkpoint function on the dataframe

Comment: I updated my problem with the solution problem fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*****************the solution*******************

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("test")
    .config("spark.local", "local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(path_checkpoint)
```

and after i call the checkpoint function on the dataframe